# <c:if> can't work?

Tags: arrays, jsp, el

Now I can get an EO from server, there is an array in the EO. I just want to get the value from the array, how I can get it ?

Here is the code in jsp:

```
<c:forEach items="${ticketDiscountCriteria.ticketDiscountCarrier}" var="carrier"
                    varStatus="carrierStatus">
                     for ( var j = 0; j < searchTicketDiscountForm.ticketDiscountCarrier.length; j++) {
                        var value = searchTicketDiscountForm.ticketDiscountCarrier[j].value;
                        alert(value);
                        <c:if test = "${carrier==value}">
                            alert(carrier.value);
                            searchTicketDiscountForm.ticketDiscountCarrier[j].checked = true;
                            break;
                        </c:if >
                     }
                </c:forEach>
```

Another code is EO :

```
public class TicketDiscountCriteria implements java.io.Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 8427162334846611072L;
private String[] ticketDiscountCarrier;

public String[] getTicketDiscountCarrier() {
    return ticketDiscountCarrier;
}
public void setTicketDiscountCarrier(String[] ticketDiscountCarrier) {
    this.ticketDiscountCarrier = ticketDiscountCarrier;
}
}
```

How can I get the value in array and use it to compare with checkbox value? Please help me.

Comment: Learn client-server architecture first before you can develop real applications.

Answer (score 0):

Do you understand that the JSP code there will run server side and that it will write javascript to the page that will run client side? I haven't read to see if the code makes sense but that initial for loop will result in the writing of a number of javascript for loops to the page.

Use your jsp for loop code to add your `ticketDiscountCarrier` DOM elements - this will require your server side code to return **all** possible elements, not just those checked. Alternatively, use two objects, one for all and one for discounted - but both served from the server. Either way you can now set their checked state on creation, putting the load on the server and not on the client. If I have misunderstood and this is somehow being used asynchronously, ditch the jsp code completely and parse the data with pure javascript.

Over Simplified (allCarriers is an object with String name and boolean discounted):

```
<c:forEach items="${ticketDiscountCriteria.allCarriers}" var="carrier">
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${carrier.discounted == true}">
                <input type="checkbox" name="ticketDiscountCarrier" value="${carrier.name}" checked="checked">${carrier.name}
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <input type="checkbox" name="ticketDiscountCarrier" value="${carrier.name}">${carrier.name}
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
    </c:forEach>
```